# Graded Index fiber

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

In the following picture of a graded index fiber two different modes are depicted. One is a higher mode which is propagating towards the core-cladding interface and one is through the higher refractive index region. What will happen at the core-cladding interface with the higher mode is there any small amount of evanescent field which will pass the core cladding interface or all of it will reflect back ? Second in case of multiple modes at what point they will intersect with each other ? in the case of single mode fiber there will be no ray directed to core cladding interface but still we get evanescent field what are the origin of this in single mode fiber ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, be careful about mixing rays and modes. Your picture shows a ray-optics view of multimode fiber, but your text talks about modes. Some of your questions are best answered in terms of rays and some are best answered in terms of modes.

Generally, fiber is characterized by a [numerical aperture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture), which you'll find listed on its datasheet. The numerical aperture is given by

$ NA = n \sin(\theta) $

where *n* is the index of refraction of the medium the approaching ray is travelling in (probably air, with $n \approx 1$, in your example), and θ is the maximum angle that ray can have and still achieve total internal reflection within the fiber.

Light entering the fiber at angles greater than the maximum given by the NA spec will generate radiating modes and have large attenuation along the fiber. Light entering at angles less than the maximum will be totally reflected and propagate with low loss. Obviously nothing is perfect and light entering at angles very close to the limiting angle might have higher attenuation than axial rays but not so high as very poorly confined ones.

> Second in case of multiple modes at what point they will intersect with each other ?

I'm going to answer your second question first, because this question is about rays rather than modes.

There are lots of different ways the index can be varied in multimode fiber. In a step index fiber, there wouldn't be any particular place where the rays are guaranteed to reconverge.

In the case of parabolic grading (which is the most common type of multimode fiber for communications applications), however, all rays entering at the center of the core will reconverge periodically as they travel along the fiber. The distance between the points of convergence depends on the parameters of the index profile of the fiber. You can find formulas for this at [this web page](http://welcome.gofoton.com/product/selfoc-grin-lens/) (click the tab for "Physics of SELFOC").

> What will happen at the core-cladding interface with the higher mode is there any small amount of evanescent field which will pass the core cladding interface or all of it will reflect back ?

Okay, now you ask specifically about *evanscent fields*. Now we have to talk about modes rather than rays.

Generally when you talk about a dielectric waveguide, there is always an evanescent field associated with the total internal reflection at the waveguide boundaries. This is because without a conductive barrier, there's nothing to force the fields to zero at the boundary.

In the case of step-index multimode fiber, all modes (whether axial or strongly angled) will have an evanescent field in the cladding.

In the case of graded index fiber, the central modes may be very well confined so that the evanescent field is negligible, although it is not mathematically zero. Modes with more power at the perimeter of the core will have more evanescent field. There will be a continuum between the two, and it would be up to you to determine at what point the evanescent component is negligible for your needs.

> In the case of single mode fiber there will be no ray directed to core cladding interface but still we get evanescent field what are the origin of this in single mode fiber ?

Single-mode fiber really can't be analyzed in terms of ray optics, so we don't talk about whether rays are or aren't directed axially or otherwise.

As I mentioned above, all modes in a step-index dielectric waveguide will have an evanescent wave in the cladding. A single-mode fiber is just a special case of a step-index waveguide with dimensions chosen so that only a single propagating mode is supported at the wavelength of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its very precise and nice explanation. a point from Graded index fibre , That means the the axial modes will propagate with higher velocity than the others as they will experience high refractive index core distribution. Is that how the multipath or modal dispersion is reduced ?